# Substitutions of method in graalvm

Tags: graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I am trying to substitute a method inside a library while building native image however I can't get it to work. I have made a sample project on [github](https://github.com/vgodara/graal-substitutions) . When I try to run native-image -jar target/graal-substitutions-full.jar -H:+ReportPerformedSubstitutions. The method I am trying to substitute is missing from the report can someone tell me what is it I am missing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Could you specify which version of GraalVM you're using? Also, i would in general recommend to stay away from Substitutions, they are a non-API, internal mechanism of native-image.

Comment: Sorry my bad didn't update it. Substitution works fine stand alone however. I can't get it work with Netty.